# Setting the AUTO_INCREMENT of userid

Tags: php, mysql

guys, how can i set the auto_increment of my userid something like this:

i want to start it in 200, then increment by 10 with a maximum value of 1000..

how will i code it using php?

please help me.. :-(

Comment: You want a maximum of 80 users?

Comment: **Why** do you want that? An auto-increment value was designed to allow you to not care about the assigned value. If you care, code the logic.

Comment: This type of logic should really be applied in your code rather than trying to force a database solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a starting point to an auto increment value, but the rest you ask (increasing by 10, and limiting at 1000) is impossible on the mySQL level.

You would need to do this in your PHP code, as a pre-check before creating a new user account. Also, I would recommend doing this in a separate, indexed `int` column.

**Update:** There is the [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) mySQL setting but it seems replication speficic, doesn't apply to your normal, single-database, myISAM setup, and is applied database-wide - it's not what you want.

Comment: +1 for remembering the --auto-increment-increment startup option, though it can't be targetted against individual tables, but applies server wide